# Autolayout Landscape for plus models

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

What is the best way to use AutoLayout and size classes in Xcode 8 when designing portrait and landscape? The portrait would be wChR and landscape would be wChC but wRhC for the Plus models of the iPhone.
Is there a way to combine those last two or do I have to design the layout 3 times? I'm using this new traits system in Xcode 8

Comment: If you don't need to make huge changes in layout, auto layout is enough expressive to do that at one time. If you want to have different layout mostly can be done using interface builder https://makeapppie.com/2016/09/05/an-introduction-to-size-classes-for-xcode-8/

Comment: Thanks for that link! But I need one view layouted in portrait that "transforms" into 3 in landscape. So I will need size classes

Comment: From IB you can install views and constraints for a particular size classes, they won't be visible in other cases

Comment: I know, but I need to do it for both, normal iPhone landscape and iPhone Plus landscape right? I wanted to somehow "combine" those to, like with a wAny hC size class. But that seems not possible